# generated-stories-entry.js error for rule 'import/no-unresolved'

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, storybook

I have added storybook to my Vue project with `vue add storybook`.

This has added several dependencies to my project, e.g. in my `package.json` I find this among others:

```
"vue": "~2.6.14",
"@storybook/vue": "6.4.19",
"vue-cli-plugin-storybook": "~2.1.0",
"eslint": "~6.8.0",
```

Now I am trying to run the storybook server with `npm run storybook:serve` but I get an error:

[image: Error from storybook:serve]

I have been trying different things, like configuring the 'import/no-unresolved' rule to be off, `emitError: false` on the `eslist-loader` inside `.eslintrc`, skipping the linter plugin in the webpack configuration, etc. Nothing worked and each attempt just produced new errors.

Currently I have no explicit `es-linter` nor `webpack` configuration at all. *But* if I comment a line inside `node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js` like this:

`// emitter(new ESLintError(messages));`

then **it all works**.

I don't want to be commenting out lines inside a library, I would like to have a proper solution and understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I had to add the `eslint-plugin-import` package:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import
```

And add the plugin to the `eslint` configuration:

```
"plugins": [
    "import"
]
```

Comment: Upgraded storybook from 6.3 to 6.4 and literally spent hours trying to fix the same error you encountered. Your solution fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For me the suggested answer didn’t work, what fix it in the end was to ignore those files in eslint configuration:

```
"ignorePatterns": [
      "generated-stories-entry.js",
      "storybook-init-framework-entry.js"
    ],
```